# Why are Gnome settings not starting in Lunar Lobster?

Tags: gnome, settings

I started working with UNIX back in '89, but I was never a sysadmin. I recently upgraded from **kinetic** to **lunar**. It took a while to update everything, reinstall all the usual IDE, apps, compilers, browsers, etc but I finally had it all running.

Among the novelties, I got `Python` going from 3.10.7 to 3.11.2, and `Gnome` from 43.? to 44.0. I looked around and apparently it's advisable to upgrade `Gnome` to 44.1, but I cannot find a way to do this other than compiling from source.

My laptop is an LG Gram (LG Electronics 14Z90Q-G.AD7BF) with these goodies (abridged):

```bash
$ lspci -v
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0c) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: LG Electronics, Inc. Alder Lake-P Integrated Graphics Controller

00:06.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 12th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x4 Controller #0 (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Subsystem: LG Electronics, Inc. 12th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x4 Controller
```

Earlier this week, **Settings** stopped opening. I get a small spinner and then nothing. I cannot change screens or any other configuration. From bash, I get:

```bash
$ gnome-control-center

19:23:41.4587       GStreamer-Play[18516]:   ERROR: GtkGstPlay: 'playbin' element not found, please check your setup
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

When I try harder, I get:

```bash
$ sudo gnome-control-center 

19:38:13.2118                  Gtk[24510]: WARNING: Unable to acquire session bus: Failed to execute child process “dbus-launch” (No such file or directory)
19:38:13.3836                dconf[24510]: WARNING: failed to commit changes to dconf: Failed to execute child process “dbus-launch” (No such file or directory)
Error creating rfkill proxy: Failed to execute child process “dbus-launch” (No such file or directory)
```

This time, the Settings window opens, but it;s not even in dark mode like the rest of the system and, whatever change I try, new lines keep appearing, like:

```bash
19:39:48.0455      cc-ubuntu-panel[24510]: WARNING: No gedit is installed here. Colors won't be updated. Please fix your installation.
19:39:48.0458                dconf[24510]: WARNING: failed to commit changes to dconf: Failed to execute child process “dbus-launch” (No such file or directory)
19:39:48.0849  cc-background-panel[24510]: WARNING: Error creating proxy: Failed to execute child process “dbus-launch” (No such file or directory)
```

And these just for clicking on **Appeaarance**!

I did both:

```bash
$ sudo apt install gedit
$ sudo apt install dbus-x11
```

and some errors disappeared, but still **Settings** won't open without `sudo` and it won't open from the UI. Also, opening with `sudo`, it now shows some progress but **Screen displays** shows nothing and keeps logging:

```bash
19:48:17.3111     cc-display-panel[25888]: WARNING: Missing property 'ApplyMonitorsConfigAllowed' on DisplayConfig API
19:48:17.3111     cc-display-panel[25888]: WARNING: Missing property 'NightLightSupported' on DisplayConfig API
19:48:17.3113     cc-display-panel[25888]: WARNING: no sunset data, using 16.00
19:48:17.3113     cc-display-panel[25888]: WARNING: no sunrise data, using 8.00
19:48:17.3119     cc-display-panel[25888]: WARNING: no sunset data, using 16.00
19:48:17.3119     cc-display-panel[25888]: WARNING: no sunrise data, using 8.00
19:48:17.3119     cc-display-panel[25888]: WARNING: Error calling GetCurrentState: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Name "org.gnome.Mutter.DisplayConfig" does not exist
19:48:17.3126     cc-display-panel[25888]: WARNING: Missing property 'ApplyMonitorsConfigAllowed' on DisplayConfig API
19:48:17.3126     cc-display-panel[25888]: WARNING: Missing property 'NightLightSupported' on DisplayConfig API
19:48:17.3130     cc-display-panel[25888]: WARNING: Error calling GetCurrentState: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Name "org.gnome.Mutter.DisplayConfig" does not exist
19:48:27.7981     cc-display-panel[25888]: WARNING: no sunset data, using 16.00
19:48:27.7981     cc-display-panel[25888]: WARNING: no sunrise data, using 8.00
19:48:37.8030     cc-display-panel[25888]: WARNING: no sunset data, using 16.00
19:48:37.8031     cc-display-panel[25888]: WARNING: no sunrise data, using 8.00
19:48:48.4884     cc-display-panel[25888]: WARNING: no sunset data, using 16.00
19:48:48.4885     cc-display-panel[25888]: WARNING: no sunrise data, using 8.00
19:48:58.7981     cc-display-panel[25888]: WARNING: no sunset data, using 16.00
19:48:58.7982     cc-display-panel[25888]: WARNING: no sunrise data, using 8.00
19:49:08.7968     cc-display-panel[25888]: WARNING: no sunset data, using 16.00
19:49:08.7969     cc-display-panel[25888]: WARNING: no sunrise data, using 8.00
19:49:18.7966     cc-display-panel[25888]: WARNING: no sunset data, using 16.00
19:49:18.7966     cc-display-panel[25888]: WARNING: no sunrise data, using 8.00
19:49:28.7964     cc-display-panel[25888]: WARNING: no sunset data, using 16.00
19:49:28.7964     cc-display-panel[25888]: WARNING: no sunrise data, using 8.00
```

This is my work laptop and I'm burning through deadlines like that's my job. I should be looking at FastAPI and React. I get the same behaviour with Wayland and Xorg. I need help urgently.

What can I do?

### EDIT 2023-05-03

If I delete the file `~/.config/dconf/user`, I then can open **Settings**, but it still crashes whenever I try going to **Multitasking**. Is this progress?

Comment: The upgrade process you described in your first two paragraphs, is... well.... strange to me.

Comment: Not so much, I guess. One fine morning last week, my laptop just informed me that the Lobster was in town and if I wanted to upgrade. I said yes and it just happened. Took some 20mins, hands-free. Was this a bad choice?

Comment: You mentioned that you upgraded, but then at some point later you started running into problems, correct? Or did you immediately experience problems after upgrading? I'm also assuming that you're still running the default Gnome (44.0), or did you upgrade or attempt to upgrade to 44.1? Finally, have you tried doing a bit of diagnostics on your machine by running `sudo dmesg` and/or checking logs (Logs GUI, which should show similar results as running `dmesg`). Also, have you checked the health of your drive(s) (for nothing more than reducing possible variables related to this issue)?

Comment: @richbl, thank you for the suggestions. I'm going to follow up on those. For now, I did not see issues immediately upon upgrading to the Lobster, only a couple weeks afterwards. I also tried to upgrade to Gnome 44.1 (announced with amny bug fixes!), but I could not find a way that didn't involve cloning / recompiling, not sure why. This is my work laptop. I cannot risk downtime. This is an out-of-the-box (early April) LG Gram, still smelling like new. I'll check disk health but anything below 100% would be a surprise. Instructions on easy 44.1 upgrade would be very welcome.